# LINQ group by many values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have multiple `MyObject` instances which need to be grouped by their types `MyType` (many per object). Only the most current object (defined by `MyObject.Date`) for each type is needed.

The following code achieves this goal with nested foreach statements.

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> objects = ...;
var grouped = new Dictionary<MyType, MyObject>();
foreach (MyObject obj in objects.OrderBy(x => x.Date))
    foreach (MyType type in obj.Types)
        grouped[type] = obj;
```

How can it be rewritten with the LINQ method syntax using `GroupBy`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. It _seems_ like what you want is to produce more than one grouping, i.e. one grouping for each possible `MyType` value (as opposed to a single group where each group of the grouping represents some combination of `MyType` values). If so, you should be able to simply project the collection of possible `MyType` values into groupings based on each of those values. **What have you tried?** Please fix your question so that it includes a proper [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and ...

Comment: ... what _specifically_ you need help with. Please also make sure that your description is unambiguous (note that a detailed explanation of inputs and expected outputs goes a long way toward providing this sort of clarify, something lacking in the current version of the question).

Comment: @peter-duniho I'm sorry if my question wasn't understandable. You are correct, I want to produce one grouping for each contained `MyType` value. The provided code already achieves the goal outlined in the first paragraph, yet I'm wondering how it could be written using LINQ `GroupBy` instead of nested foreach statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you need to upgrade your `MyType` object (if you haven't done so already) to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. You can't use a reference type as a key for a dictionary without doing so, otherwise it only groups by reference in memory.

Here's my version of you `MyType`:

```
public class MyType
{
    public int Id;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyType other)
        {
            return other.Id == this.Id;
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Next, we need some sample data to work with:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> objects = new[]
{
    new MyObject()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(1969, 7, 20),
        Types = new List<MyType>()
        {
            new MyType() { Id = 1 },
            new MyType() { Id = 2 },
        }
    },
    new MyObject()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(1986, 4, 26),
        Types = new List<MyType>()
        {
            new MyType() { Id = 2 },
            new MyType() { Id = 3 },
        }
    },
};
```

Now, it's easy:

```
var query =
    from obj in objects
    orderby obj.Date descending
    from type in obj.Types
    group obj by type into gts
    from gt in gts.Take(1)
    select new
    {
        type = gts.Key,
        obj = gt
    };
    
Dictionary<MyType, MyObject> grouped =
    query
        .ToDictionary(x => x.type, x => x.obj);
```

That gives me:

[image: grouped]

---

In method syntax the query becomes:

```
Dictionary<MyType, MyObject> grouped =
    objects
        .OrderByDescending(obj => obj.Date)
        .SelectMany(obj => obj.Types, (obj, type) => new { obj, type })
        .GroupBy(x => x.type, x => x.obj)
        .SelectMany(gts => gts.Take(1), (gts, gt) => new { type = gts.Key, obj = gt })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.type, x => x.obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's definitely the solution, yet I'm not that familiar with the query syntax. can it also be written in the method syntax?

Comment: @morrow - Yes, it can. Query syntax is just syntactic sugar for method syntax in every single case. I certainly know that I prefer query syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! I'll try to get into the query syntax more.